# AXDT Eclipse Error When Making

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3

I am using Eclipse Indigo IDE for Java Developer running in OsX Lion.
I have installed AXDT but when I trying to make new As3 Project it always give me an error.

The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.axdt.as3.ui was unable to load class org.axdt.as3.ui.As3ExecutableExtensionFactory.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.axdt.as3.ui (359).

Anyone here know what I should do?